# Why must the supersymmetry generators be spinors?

Tags: supersymmetry, spinors, spin-statistics, grassmann-numbers, superalgebra

I have read in a few places (for example, at page 5 [here](http://arxiv.org/abs/0907.0039)) that the supersymmetry generators must be spinors. Quoting the reference mentioned

> The generator of the symmetry must relate two types of particles:
>   $$Q|{\rm fermion}\rangle=|{\rm boson}\rangle\qquad{}Q|{\rm boson}\rangle=|{\rm fermion}\rangle$$
>   It follows that $Q$ must be a spinor.

How does this follow?

Comment: Comment to the post (v3): Are you aware of the [spin-statistics theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spin%E2%80%93statistics_theorem)?

Comment: @Qmechanic I know that half integer spins are fermions and integer spins bosons but that's all

Answer (score 3):

Formally, the properties "bosonic" and "fermionic" are captured by the relevant objects being part of a $\mathbb{Z}_2 = \{1,-1\}$-[graded algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graded_ring#Graded_algebra) (a [superalgebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superalgebra)). The even degrees (with grading $1$) of that algebra are called "bosonic", the odd degrees (with grading $-1$) are called "fermionic".

It follows from the grading that if $xy$ is even for $y$ odd, then $x$ must be odd, and if $xy$ is odd for $y$ even, then $x$ must be odd, too.

Hence, it follows from the defining properties of supersymmetry that the generator is odd, or fermionic.